# Deleting a line which has a certein condition by using awk

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I am trying to delete specific line in a gro file.
I want to delete the lines that satisfy the if conditions.The awk code that I am currenly using is this;

```
cat doubled_system.gro | awk '{if ($2 ~ /^NA/ && $5 > 23)  print $0}' > new.gro
```

So far i manage the line that I don't want in 'new.gro' file.

I was wondering how can combine sed or grep with this if condition so that I can delete the line that I dont want in doubled_system.gro file?

Comment: First, simplify your `awk` to `awk '$2 ~ /^NA/ && $5 > 23' doubled_system.gro`   Step 2: profit.  Mutating the file in place an anti-pattern.  Just filter the output to a different file and then rename.  It is more reliable and simpler.  Any attempt to edit "in-place" will be non-atomic and potentially lead to data corruption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> manage the line that i dont want(...)delete the line that i dont want

If you have *negative* of desired output you need simply to negate condition, as you have used logical AND then it is valid target for de Morgan rule, therefore after negating

```
$2 ~ /^NA/ && $5 > 23
```

we do get

```
$2 !~ /^NA/ || $5 <= 23
```

your code does also needlessly use `if` and `cat`, as GNU `AWK` can read file by itself, after fixing that your code might look as follows

```
awk '($2 !~ /^NA/ || $5 <= 23){print $0}' doubled_system.gro > new.gro
```

which will save output without undesired line(s) into `new.gro`, after you check that it is giving correct result for all allowed input values, then you might use `-i inplace` to place file in place like so

```
awk -i inplace '($2 !~ /^NA/ || $5 <= 23){print $0}' doubled_system.gro
```

Comment: `print $0` is the default behaviour, so you could shorten to `'$2 !~ /^NA/ || $5 <= 23'`.